# How to clear components in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am new to Java programming. I developing a java app, which draws shapes (circles, lines, triangles, etc) on a windows frame. I define an abstract class `Shapes.java` to contain the framework for shapes:

```java
public abstract class Shapes {
    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
}
```

Then, I define some classes such as Circle, Line, Triangle, and Rectangle which extend from the `Shapes.java` class.

```java
public class Circle extends Shapes{
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int radius;

   public Circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.radius = radius;
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Graphics g) {
       g.drawOval(x-radius,y-radius,radius * 2, radius *2);
   }}
```

In my `Picture.java` class, I settle a JFrame and add shapes on it:

```java
public class Picture extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean isClear = false;

    private ArrayList<Shapes> listShape = new ArrayList<Shapes>();
    private class ShapesPanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(isClear)
            return;
        else
            for (Shapes s : listShape)
                s.draw(g);         
    }

    public void add(Shapes s){
        listShape.add(s);
    }

    public Picture(int width, int height, String title) throws HeadlessException {
        ShapesPanel mypanel = new ShapesPanel();
        add(mypanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.setTitle(title);
    }  

    public void draw(){
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(width, height);
        setVisible(true);
        repaint();
    }

    void clear(){//clear the componets in the JPanel
        this.setIsClear(true); 
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    private void setIsClear(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.isClear = b;
    }
}
```

But when I invoke the `clear()` method in the main class, the program cannot repaint the new shapes again. How can I fix the bugs? Thanks.

```java
public class MyPic {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Picture pic = new Picture(420, 300, "shape demo");
        Circle c1 = new Circle(320,80,80);
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
        Triangle t1 = new Triangle(100,100,200,100,150,50);
        Line l1 = new Line(0,205,400,50);

        pic.add(c1);
        pic.add(r1);
        pic.add(t1);
        pic.add(l1);
        pic.clear();
        pic.draw();
        pic.add(l1);//add l1 again
    }
}
```

Comment: i think in the clear() method, instead of this.validate(); , it should be this.revalidate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so by calling `clear()` you set a variable `isClear` to `true`. And then in your `paintComponent` you say:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(isClear)
        return;
```

which means 'if isClear is true, don't paint anything' (which it is, you just set it to true with `clear()`). So, no wonder.

Anyway, I think in the `clear` method, you might want to do `listShape.clear()` instead of setting that boolean.

Comment: Happy 4 figure rep. :)